# Update WooCommerce User programmatically when creating a user

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, user-data, usermetadata

Im trying to create a new user programmatically trough a form but Im having problem with getting the phone numer and country set trough `wp_create_user` - why wont it take the values? First and last name works as expected.

Relevant code:

```
$user_id = wp_create_user( $username, $random_password, $user_email ); 
    wp_update_user([
    'ID' => $user_id,
     'first_name' => rgar( $entry, '20.3' ),
     'last_name'  => rgar( $entry, '20.6' ),
     'phone'      => rgar( $entry, '16' ),
     'country'  => rgar( $entry, '24.6' )
    ]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In with WooCommerce the phone and the country are billing fields so the right user meta keys are:

- `billing_country` *(Remember that you need to set a valid country code)*
- `billing_phone`

You will also need to set the `billing_email`, `billing_first_name` and `billing_last_name`

So your code is going to be instead, replacing also your `wp_create_user()` function by:

```php
    $username = rgar( $entry, '20.3' );
    $email    = rgar( $entry, '10' );
    $password = wp_generate_password( 12, false );

    $user_data = array(
        'user_login' => $username,
        'user_pass'  => $password,
        'user_email' => $email,
        'role'       => 'customer',
        'first_name' => rgar( $entry, '20.3' ),
        'last_name'  => rgar( $entry, '20.6' ),
    );

    $user_id  = wp_insert_user( $user_data ); // Create user with specific user data
```

#### Then to add the WooCommerce user data there is 2 ways:

**1). Using `WC_Customer` Object and methods:**

```
    $customer = new WC_Customer( $user_id ); // Get an instance of the WC_Customer Object from user Id

    $customer->set_billing_first_name( rgar( $entry, '20.3' ) );
    $customer->set_billing_last_name( rgar( $entry, '20.6' ) );
    $customer->set_billing_country( rgar( $entry, '24.6') );
    $customer->set_billing_phone( rgar( $entry, '16' ) );
    $customer->set_billing_email( $email );

    $customer->save(); // Save data to database (add the user meta data)
```

**2) Or using WordPress `update_user_meta()` function** *(the old way)*:

```
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_first_name', rgar( $entry, '20.3') );
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_last_name', rgar( $entry, '20.6') );
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_country', rgar( $entry, '24.6') );
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_phone', rgar( $entry, '16') );
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_email', $email );
```

Comment: Thank you! Getting closer. With this I get the number set correctly, but the country doesn't update for some reason

Comment: Hmm how do I get the country code set for the selected country (the country gets selected from a dropdown county field)

Comment: Thank you - I read up a bit on it and I see the problem - seems Gravity forms has a filter hook to convert the country names at least. Ill give it a shot first before I create a new question. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can add `country` and `phone` as a User meta and save it in the User Meta table:

```
add_user_meta( $user_id, 'country', rgar( $entry, '24.6'));
add_user_meta( $user_id, 'phone', rgar( $entry, '16'));
```

WordPress Codex : [Click Here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_user_meta/)

Comment: Thanks! Dont get it to work though, should I call it in the array somehow? My php is not that strong..